ValueError: Value of min_samples_split must be a optuna distribution
start = time.time()
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
parameters = {
'min_samples_split': range(2, 6),
'min_samples_leaf': range(1, 6),
'max_depth': range(2, 6)
}
oscv = OptunaSearchCV(
model,
parameters,
cv=5,
n_trials=20,
scoring='roc_auc',
random_state=0
)
oscv.fit(X_train, y_train)
oscv_search_time = time.time() - start
print(f'Search time:{oscv_search_time}')
print('best_params_', oscv.best_params_)
print('ROC-AUC', oscv.best_score_)
